# Ubuntu 16.10 stuck on 2 dots while booting from liveUSB

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, 16.10

I was installing Ubuntu 16.10 on my ASUS ROG-551vw when it wouldn't proceed further than the 5 dot loading screen. The dots stopped moving as well within 10 seconds and got stuck at 2 dots. Checked the disk for errors and found none. Confirmed SHA256 checksum and it is legit okay. I don't know where I'm going wrong but it just won't work.